# Get Tangent value from a Degree value in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, percentage, degrees

I am trying to calculate the percent from a degree value using Xcode Swift.

For example:

1. I have a degree value of 0.2159
2. The Tangent value for this degree based off the tangent table is 0.00377
3. To find degrees, multiply tangent*100 which makes the percent 0.377%

Now, I can't for the life of me find a library in Xcode or even a package that would do this work for me. The tangent table is huge, so I am looking for a function that would do the conversion from step 1 to step 2 for me.

Thanks so much!

Comment: SwiftUI is a UI framework -- you probably just mean Swift.

Comment: There is a `tan(_:)` method, which accepts radian, not degree. So convert first your degree value into radians, and apply `tan()` on it. Multiply then by 100...